# Is my trading strategy search methodology sound?

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, machine-learning

I'm building an algorithmic trading business. I'd be grateful for informed comments and opinions on my trading strategy search methodology.

**Goal**

Develop (profitable!) fully automated intra-day trading strategies.

**Markets**

I'm focusing on FX futures and equity index futures on CME and LIFFE. Becuase:

- I know these markets best
- I can get roundtrip times of 10s ms
- Futures margin means big leverage for my small account

**Data**

I'm buying in Level 1 tickdata from the exchanges. I don't think level 2 data would add anything because I wont have low enough latency to make use of it. A typical contract might have 1M data points per day.

**Search Strategy**

I have a bias towards machine learning specifically SVM/R. My plan goes like this

1. Choose an instrument and forecast horizon (5-120 seconds)
2. Assembly a large stable of features e.g.

   - Resampled lagged time series and returns
   - Wavelet transform of the above
   - Measures of [information entropy](http://www.unifr.ch/econophysics/papers/201011/7080368565.pdf)
   - Some indicators from [Operators on Inhomogeneous Time Series](http://ssrn.com/abstract=208278) (This is 11 years old now but I've yet to see anything that meaningfully expands on it)
   - If can hold down the vomit some 'Traditional Technical Analysis' indicators
3. Choose a subset of features with genetic search. The objective function is the MSE of the n-fold SVM cross validation
4. Build the final SVM with the best parameter selection.
5. Hope that the highest confidence predictions form the basis of a profitable trading strategy

In your experience do you think a strategy developed like this can hope to make money on liquid equity index and FX futures? If not why not?

Comment: Hi David, welcome to quant.SE and thanks for posting your question.  I'm not sure what exactly would qualify as an answer to your question, do you have any questions beyond a yes/no response?  Also, I would counsel that you consider the bigger picture, such as what is the source of your profits, who is your competition, and what gives *you* an edge.

Comment: Hi Tal, Thanks for replying. I've changed the question to make it more specific. On the edge question my thesis goes something like this: there are limited pockets of predictability out there, I can detect some of them using machine learning. I can afford to be interested in opportunities that fall below the radar of others as I am trading my own account. From my experience I don't think this is too a crowded niche.

Comment: So how did your plan go? :)

Answer (score 21):

This is a very interesting question.  I believe it is getting a lot of up-votes from people who have wondered the same thing and don't know where to begin, whereas you have at least laid out a reasonable-sounding plan.  I commend you for that.  However, it is not clear to me what you're trying to learn by posting this question.  In my opinion, the plan you laid out seems like a reasonable start but, by itself, will not lead you to a profitable trading strategy.  That is just my opinion, is there something else you'd like to know?  The rest of my answer consists of further comments.

If you haven't already, I recommend you read [Ernest Chan's Quantitative Trading](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470284889).  He devotes an entire chapter to "Fishing for Ideas: Where can we find good strategies?"  I should mention, however, that he is skeptical of your bias towards machine learning:

> At the risk of oversimplification, we can characterize artificial intelligence
>   (AI) as trying to fit past data points into a function with many, many parameters.
>   This is the case for some of the favorite tools of AI: neural networks,
>   decision trees, and genetic algorithms. With many parameters, we can for sure
>   capture small patterns that no human can see. But do these patterns persist?
>   Or are they random noises that will never replay again? Experts in AI assure
>   us that they have many safeguards against fitting the function to transient
>   noise. And indeed, such tools have been very effective in consumer marketing
>   and credit card fraud detection. Apparently, the patterns of consumers and
>   thefts are quite consistent over time, allowing such AI algorithms to work even
>   with a large number of parameters. However, from my experience, these safeguards
>   work far less well in financial markets prediction, and overfitting to
>   the noise in historical data remains a rampant problem. As a matter of fact,
>   I have built financial predictive models based on many of these AI algorithms in
>   the past. Every time a carefully constructed model that seems to work marvels
>   in backtest came up, they inevitably performed miserably going forward. The
>   main reason for this seems to be that the amount of statistically independent
>   financial data is far more limited compared to the billions of independent consumer
>   and credit transactions available. (You may think that there is a lot of tickby-
>   tick financial data to mine, but such data is serially correlated and far from
>   independent.)

The primary reason I believe your plan is incomplete is that you haven't demonstrated an edge.  All the techniques you mention, machine learning, inhomogeneous time series, wavelets, are not new.  If you can demonstrate a novel yet useful way of combining these methods, then maybe you have something.  But be aware that there is **huge** competition in FX and index equity futures, and it is *extremely* unlikely that no one has tried something along the lines of what you are trying.

Also, just because you think you know a market *best* does not make it the **best market for you.**  For that, I point you once again towards Chan's book.  He points out that your strategy should match your

- working hours
- programming skills
- trading capital
- personal goals

Think carefully about each of these.  Note that prior knowledge of a given market is not on the list.  That can be picked up relatively easily.  In fact, given that you already mention you have a small account, I really see no reason for you to be in such liquid markets, particularly as getting the sort of ultra-low latency to beat other market participants in a market-making type strategy will take an investment of many $100k.